# Как скрейпить данные с сайта?

Tags: php, веб-скрейпинг

Не могу никак решить проблему:
Пробовал использовать file_get_contents, cURL, +- proxy (на один запрос отдельный айпи), но сайт отвечает так, что все мои такие запросы блокирует или сразу, или почти сразу, может есть какая-то альтернатива или обход защиты от парсинга? Или может я что-то делаю не так?

Другие сайты ок парсит, а тот, что мне нужен не хочет.
Единственный код, который испольняется (cURL)

```
$url = 'http://somedomain';
//$proxy = 'someip:someport';
//$proxyauth = 'user:password';

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,$url);
//curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PROXY, $proxy);
//curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PROXYUSERPWD, $proxyauth);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 1);
$curl_scraped_page = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);

echo $curl_scraped_page;
```

в ответ получаю что-то типо:
HTTP/1.1 416 Requested Range Not Satisfiable Server

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

После того, как добавил:

```
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_USERAGENT,'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/65.0.3325.162 Safari/537.36');
```

Сервер возвращает статус 200, но ничего не возвращает, только редиректит через секунд 5 на адрес, типо:
http://localproject.devel/distil_r_blocked.html?requestId=b63587ec-02bd-4b67-9d24-e5851df41f20&httpReferrer=%2F

Comment: если вы там в бесконечном цикле запускаете скачивание всех страниц, то не удивительно. делайте паузы, то на дос атаку скорее похоже

Comment: "Представиться" как YandexBot или GoogleBot?

Comment: нет, одиночный запрос на одну страницу

Comment: @russell, через какое количество запросов с одного ip его блокируют?

Comment: это не совсем мне понятно, бывает раз 3-5 загружаю все ок, потом меняю айпи и лочат с первого раза даже

Comment: если представиться как YandexBot или GoogleBot - возвращает статус 416

Comment: Это называется **скрейпинг**, а не парсинг. И мер защиты против него существует великое множество. Универсального для всех сайтов ответа нет, это извечная война.

Comment: Судя по URL редиректу на сайте который вы пытаетесь парсить стоит код от https://www.distilnetworks.com/ , это один из мировых лидеров по защите от парсинга и bad bots. Как бы обойти их защиту - не просто, там работает добрая сотня специалистов. Много чего предусмотрено. На днях я скрейпил сайт с их защитой на чистом PHP - не получилось. Как итог использовал сторонний софт и все получилось нормально (удивительно кстати). Софт - Offline Explorer, с кастомными юзерагентами.